# how to check if panel contains a labels and how to access the labels by their names C# winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, panel

i am developing a system in which labels text will store in text file etc, i want to check if a specific panel contains a label and how to access these labels by their names? panel1.Contains(label1) is for just accessing one variable but how can i access all the labels that a panel contains?

Comment: You can't access them by their names, but you can set the Name property (totally different thing from variable name!!) and find them by that. Or stuff them into a Dictionary to be sure of the uniqueness..

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get all the labels on your panel.

```
foreach (Control c in panel.Controls)
{
    if (c is Label)
    {
        //do what you want with your label
    }
}
```

Comment: "p" should be "c"

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Label> ll= panel.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();
List<string> ListOfText = ( from l in ll where l.Name.Contains("WhatYouWant") select l.Text).ToList();
```